# Does this maths code work

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a maths app and with this code im using i always get the same answer with different numbers. The Program runs fine, it loads and i can enter in data but always get the answer 0.0.

```
((- numB + Math.sqrt((Math.pow(numB, 2))-4*numA*numC))/2*numA)
```

full code

```
public class MainActivityQuadraticEquation extends Activity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_quadraticequation);

        Button btnBack = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnBack);

        btnBack.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() 
        {
         public void onClick(View v)
            {
             Log.i("Click Occured","You Clicked the Back button");

             Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivityQuadraticEquation.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }

        });

    }

    public void Calculate(View v)
    {
        EditText inputA = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.InputA);
        EditText inputB = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.InputB);
        EditText inputC = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.InputC);

        Integer numA = Integer.parseInt(inputA.getText().toString()), numB = Integer.parseInt(inputB.getText().toString()), numC = Integer.parseInt(inputC.getText().toString());
        Integer ans_1 = (int) ((- numB + Math.sqrt((Math.pow(numB, 2))-4*numA*numC))/2*numA);
        Integer ans_2 = (int) ((- numB - Math.sqrt((Math.pow(numB, 2))-4*numA*numC))/2*numA);

        double ans_1a = ans_1;
        double ans_2a = ans_2;
        String ans1 = String.valueOf(ans_1a);
        String ans2 = String.valueOf(ans_2a);


        TextView answer1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Ans);
        TextView answer2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Ans2);
        answer1.setText("Answer 1: " + ans1);
        //System.out.println("Answer 1: " + ans1);
        answer2.setText("Answer 2: " + ans2); 
        //System.out.println("Answer 2: " + ans2);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

It does but it doesnt work

Comment: Are you trying to solve `numA * x * x + numB * x + numC = 0`? If yes, specify it in your question.

Comment: One simple debugging trick that can help is to print out (in some way) the intermediate results of your calculations in order to see where the error might be occurring. I'm not sure how this is done in Android, but know that with standard Java we use either System.out.println(...) statements or logging statements or a debugger.

Comment: *Why* are you casting the result to `int`?  By their very nature these should be `double`.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is not with the math. It may be that something is going wrong with parsing or the `TextEdit` object is not behaving as you expect, but [the calculation itself should work](http://ideone.com/klUZh1):

```
int numA = 1;
int numB = -6;
int numC = 8;
double ans_1 = (-numB + Math.sqrt(numB * numB - 4 * numA * numC)) / (2 * numA);
double ans_2 = (-numB - Math.sqrt(numB * numB - 4 * numA * numC)) / (2 * numA);
System.out.println(ans_1 + "\n" + ans_2);
```

which outputs:

```
4.0
2.0
```

Of course, as it has been suggested, you should stick with using doubles for all of this. Also, it's not clear how you handle cases where there are no real solutions (when `Math.sqrt` is invoked with a negative number). Also, it seems to work here (surprisingly), but instead of `/2*numA` you really should have `/(2 * numA)`.

Answer (score 0):

You're likely losing precision on your intermediate cast to `int`.  It's also the case that you can read in those whole number values as doubles instead, and not lose any precision in your calculation.

So, the critical part of your code becomes this:

```
double numA = Double.parseDouble(inputA.getText().toString()),
       numB = Double.parseDouble(inputB.getText().toString()),
       numC = Double.parseDouble(inputC.getText().toString());
double ans_1 = ((- numB + Math.sqrt((Math.pow(numB, 2))-4*numA*numC))/2*numA);
double ans_2 = ((- numB - Math.sqrt((Math.pow(numB, 2))-4*numA*numC))/2*numA);

String ans1 = String.valueOf(ans_1);
String ans2 = String.valueOf(ans_2);
```

The intermediate casts to `int` and/or `Integer` are unhelpful and unnecessary.

Comment: Why `Double ans_1` instead of `double ans_1`?

Comment: "You're likely losing precision". Can you explain how that would cause answers to always be 0 as OP claims? The actual calculation is almost completely done in floating point.

Comment: @ZongZhengLi Maybe OP is unlucky that all numbers he tried always result in between `+1` and `-1`.

Comment: @ZongZhengLi:  Casts to (int) truncate the decimal part, so that loses precision.

Comment: Yes of course, but that would only result in 0 for a very small set of solutions.

Comment: I can't be certain of the input that they're putting in, but the part after the decimal is what concerns me.  If they do use a higher value which will get them a quadratic that is -1 >= x U 1 <= x, it will only show the integer portion.

Answer (score 0):

- Don't cast your `ans_1` and `ans_2` into an `int`. You are losing precision, assign it to `double`.

  - `double ans_1 = ((-numB ...)`
- Choose input numbers wisely - make sure that your Quadratic formula works, i.e. `b^2 - 4ac` must be > 0 so `Math.sqrt()` can work.

I don't see any more problems with this.